# how to add an "update" attribute to a commandButton created dynamically

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I try to create a `<h:commandButton>` dynamically, from a bean. It must look like:

```
<h:commandButton actionListener="#{bean.okUpdate("1234")}" title="ok" value="ok" id="ok_1234" update:"otherComponent"/>
```

So far, the code in the bean to create this button:

```
    HtmlCommandButton okUpdate = new HtmlCommandButton();
    okUpdate.setLabel("ok");
    okUpdate.setValue("ok");
    okUpdate.setId("okUpdate_" + uuid);
    okUpdate.setActionExpression(createMethodExpression(String.format("#{bean.okUpdate('" + uuid + "')}", "ok"), null, String.class));
```

-> which code should I add so that the commandButton includes `update:"otherComponent"` as well?

Comment: The attribute "update" doesn't exist for this tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Primefaces CommandButton class [Reference here](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/4.0/primefaces-p/commandButton.html.)

```
org.primefaces.component.CommandButton.
```

It has an "`update`" value `expression`.